# How to remove objects with rm()

Tags: r

```
aaa<-function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    rm(paste("aaa",i,sep=""),pos = ".GlobalEnv")
  }
}

aaa1<-"e!f!g!h!"
aaa2<-"e!f!g!h!"
aaa()
```

I tried to remove aaa1 and aaa2 with loop, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a function that returns a character vector like that to `rm`. For example if you run

```
aaa1<-12   
x<-"aaa1"
rm(x)
```

it will remove `x`, not `aaa1`. So you can't remove variables by giving a list of strings to `rm()` like that.

However, `rm()` does have `list=` parameter that does allow you to specify a character vector. so

```
aaa<-function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    rm(list=paste("aaa",i,sep=""),pos = ".GlobalEnv")
  }
}

aaa1<-"e!f!g!h!"
aaa2<-"e!f!g!h!"
aaa()
```

will work.

Comment: `rm(list=ls(pattern="aaa\\d+$"))` or something similar is probably preferable to looping though.

Comment: @thelatemail Good point. I was just focusing on the `rm` part. I can't imagine the real function looks exactly like this, but i guess you never know.

Comment: @thelatemail rm(list=ls(pattern="aaa\\d+$")) doesn't seem to work. you may run rm(aaa1) after aaa().

Comment: @stata - it works just fine for me and removes aaa1 and aaa2.